# I created a ground, but I can't see the ground in openGL. How can I fix it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, 3d

This code works with no errors but the ground that I created is not seen on the screen after running the program. I want to see the whole ground on the screen.

How can I fix the code?

```
#define A glVertex3f (0.5,  1.2, 0)
#define B glVertex3f (1, 2, 0)
#define C glVertex3f (2, 1.4, 0)
#define D glVertex3f ( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5)
#define E glVertex3f (-0.5,  0.5,  0.5)
#define F glVertex3f (-0.5, -0.5,  0.5)
#define G glVertex3f ( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5)
#define H glVertex3f ( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5)
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <glut.h>
float distance = 5.0;
int longitude = 0, latitude = 0, ainc = 5;
int lastx = -1, lasty = -1;
int x=0,z=0;
int y;
int data[17][21]=
{{14 ,25, 45 ,55 ,68 ,70 ,84 ,91 ,97, 101 ,105 ,105 ,105, 105 ,110 ,110,   110, 110 ,110, 110, 110},
{5, 18, 43, 62 ,73, 82, 88, 94, 99, 102 ,105, 105 ,105, 105, 110, 110 ,110 ,110 ,110, 110, 110},
{5, 18 ,38 ,56, 69, 77, 86, 94, 99, 103, 106, 105, 105, 105, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110},
{5 ,9 ,31, 48, 60, 71, 81, 87, 95, 101, 106, 105, 105, 105, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110},
{5, 5, 18, 37, 49, 56, 62, 81, 91, 94, 101, 105, 105, 105, 110, 110, 110 ,110 ,110, 110, 110},
{5, 5, 12, 23 ,34, 40, 53 ,66 ,77 ,82, 97, 103, 105, 105, 109, 110, 110, 110, 110, 115, 115},
{4 ,5 ,8 ,15, 20, 24, 35, 39, 40, 77, 92, 101, 104, 104 ,105, 110, 110, 110, 115, 115, 115},
{5, 7 ,22, 36, 46, 48, 48, 44 ,50, 58, 80, 96, 96, 97, 106, 110, 110, 115, 115, 115, 115},
{4, 15 ,31 ,46 ,61, 68, 69, 63, 53, 50, 67, 82, 84, 103, 108, 110, 110, 115, 115, 115, 115},
{4, 12, 31, 46, 64, 78, 82, 80, 69, 54, 73, 71, 92, 105, 108, 110, 110, 115, 115, 115, 115},
{6, 26 ,35 ,45, 63, 75, 84, 87, 84, 74 ,77, 80, 96, 103, 108, 110, 110, 110, 115, 115, 115},
{21, 30, 46, 57 ,64 ,76 ,85 ,92 ,92, 87 ,79 ,80 ,86 ,102, 106, 110, 105 ,110, 115, 115, 115},
{27, 40, 48 ,62 ,75 ,84 ,92, 96, 97 ,94 ,88 ,80 ,80 ,91, 104, 105, 105, 105, 110, 115, 115},
{33, 43, 55, 65, 75, 87, 96, 101, 101, 101, 97, 92, 80, 80, 98, 105, 105, 105, 105, 110, 115},
{45, 50, 58, 68, 80, 91, 99, 102, 105, 105, 105, 99, 90, 80, 80, 97, 105, 105, 105, 110, 100},
{50, 60, 65, 71, 84, 95, 101, 105, 105, 107, 107, 106, 102, 101, 92, 80, 98, 104, 105, 100, 100},
{60, 70, 76, 83, 88 ,96, 103, 106 ,107, 108 ,110, 109 ,108 ,108, 106, 101 ,90, 100, 100, 100, 100}};
void display (void)
{
float xc, yc, zc;
int type = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP;   // or GL_LINE_LOOP
xc = distance * cos (latitude /180.0*M_PI) * cos (longitude/180.0*M_PI);
yc = distance * sin (latitude /180.0*M_PI);
zc = distance * cos (latitude /180.0*M_PI) * sin (longitude/180.0*M_PI);
glLoadIdentity ();
gluLookAt (xc, yc, zc,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  
glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glBegin (type);  
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
{

    z=z+20;
    for (int k = 0; k < 21; k=k+1)
    {
        y=data[i][k];
        if(y>0&&y<50)
            glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        if(y>=50&&y<80)
            glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        if(y>=80)
            glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);


        glVertex3f(x, data[i][k], z);
        x=x+20;

        }

    }


  glEnd();  // front



  glutSwapBuffers ();
  }

 void keyboard (unsigned char key, int x, int y)
 {
 switch (key) {
 case 27: case 'q': case 'Q':
exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
break;
 }
} 

void special (int key, int x, int y)
{
switch (key) {
case GLUT_KEY_UP:
distance *= 2;
break;
case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
distance /= 2;
break;
}
glutPostRedisplay ();
}

void click (int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
lastx = x;
lasty = y;
}
}

void mouse (int x, int y)
{
if (x > lastx) {
longitude = (longitude + ainc) % 360;
} else if (x < lastx) {
longitude = (longitude - ainc) % 360;
}
if (y > lasty) {
latitude = (latitude + ainc) % 360;
 } else if (y < lasty) {
latitude = (latitude - ainc) % 360;
 }
 lastx = x;
 lasty = y;
 glutPostRedisplay ();
 }

 void reshape (int w, int h)
{
glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity ();
gluPerspective (65.0, (GLfloat) w / (GLfloat) h, 1.0, 20.0);
glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity ();
glTranslatef (0.0, 0.0, -5.0);
}


 int main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
 glutInit (&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
 glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
 glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity ();
 gluPerspective(50.0, 1.0, 3.0, 7.0);
 glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
 glutDisplayFunc (display);
 glutKeyboardFunc (keyboard);
 glutSpecialFunc (special);
 glutMouseFunc (click);
 glutMotionFunc (mouse);
 glutReshapeFunc (reshape);
  glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glutMainLoop ();
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see few things which you can check
1) in reshape Fucntion glTranslatef (0.0, 0.0, -5.0) is called, just after that in display function you are calling loadIdentity() which will reset the matrix. So translate may not apply on the object you are drawing.
2) Also try changing the Z value more inwards Z axis.
3) Change your projection Far point, and FOV angle, as your X values are very higher.
 I noticed one more thing your x,y,z are global values and are not reset on reshape.
Hope it helps.